# Json Parsing issue with array of array in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, nsstring, nslog

I Have following Json as

```
{
"meta": {
    "code": 200
       }, 
"response": {
           "deals": [           {
                "id": 32373, 
            "date_added": "2011-01-13 12:12:50", 
            "end_date": "2011-01-14 10:00:00", 
            "active": 1, 
            "discount": {
                "raw": 71, 
                "formatted": "71%"
            }, 
            "price": {
                "raw": "85.00", 
                "formatted": "$85"
            }, 
            "value": {
                "raw": "300.00", 
                "formatted": "$300"
            }, 
            "purchased": 82, 
            "left": null, 
            "title": "$85 For $300 Babyface Facial At Park Avenue MedSpa", 
            "yipit_title": "71% off Babyface Facial", 
            "url": "http://yipit.com/aff/click/?deal=AvwTADtE&key=F374EFbM", 
            "yipit_url": "http://yipit.com/new-york/livingsocial/85-for-300-babyface-facial-at-park-avenue-medspa/", 
            "images": {
                "image_big": "http://d22nv2k05ynu7x.cloudfront.net/deal_images/deal/85-for-300-babyface-facial-at-park-avenue-medspa-1294920769_display_image.jpg", 
                "image_small": "http://d22nv2k05ynu7x.cloudfront.net/deal_images/deal/85-for-300-babyface-facial-at-park-avenue-medspa-1294920769_small_image.jpg"
            }, 
            "division": {
                "slug": "new-york", 
                "name": "New York", 
                "active": 1, 
                "time_zone_diff": -4, 
                "lat": "40.7142690000000000", 
                "lon": "-74.0059730000000000", 
                "url": "http://yipit.com/new-york/"
            }, 
            "tags": [
                {
                    "name": "Facial", 
                    "slug": "facial", 
                    "url": "http://yipit.com/new-york/deals/facial/"
                }, 
                {
                    "name": "Spa", 
                    "slug": "spa", 
                    "url": "http://yipit.com/new-york/deals/spa/"
                }
            ], 
            "business": {
                "name": "Park Avenue MedSpa", 
                "url": "", 
                "locations": [
                    {
                        "address": "565 Park Ave", 
                       "locality": "New York",
                        "phone": "212-593-8821", 
                        "lat": null, 
                        "lon": null
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            "source": {
                "name": "LivingSocial", 
                "slug": "livingsocial", 
                "paid": 0, 
                "url": "http://yipit.com/new-york/livingsocial"
            }
        }
    ]
}
    }
```

I am using NSJSONSerialization parse this json look like my code as

```
 NSError *jsonError;
NSMutableDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&jsonError];
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"response"] valueForKeyPath:@"deals.business.locations"];
self.tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
aData = [[Data alloc]initwithName:[[resultArray objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"address"]];
[self.tempArray addObject:aData];
```

but my address values is display as with bracket like as ("565 Park Ave") but i want only display 565 Park Ave value only. How can solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you **NSLog** an array or dictionary like this, it writes the " around strings that are longer than one word. Don't worry, your data will only be `565 Park Ave` even if the NSLog writes `"565 Park Ave"`.

It is the way `-(NSString*)description` handles strings in the two containers.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a string from the JSON aData. aData keeps the "" but the string decoded from the data won't have